# iOS UITextView - setText method not showing my text?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, xcode4.2, uitextview

I've created a `UITextView` programmatically with the follow:

```
messageBodyTxt = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(36, 204, 763, 251)];
[messageBodyTxt setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.627 green:0.627 blue:0.627 alpha:1]];
[messageBodyTxt setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[messageBodyTxt setText:@"some random text"];
```

However, the **setText** property is not showing my text.  My header file looks like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MessageView : UIView {
    UITextView *messageBodyTxt;
}

@end
```

and i've added it to my view like so:

```
[self addSubview:messageBodyTxt];
```

All of my other `UILabel`'s function properly when I use the **setText** method, however I can't seem to get the `UITextView` to show anything.

Any ideas?

Comment: try `messageBodyTxt.text = @"some random text";` instead

Comment: Where is the textview being added to the screen. What about if you change the background color to something obvious, can you still see it?, Don't see why your code wouldn't work, unless its not being used/on screen.

Comment: @AmitShah agreed.  Also, where in your view hierarchy is it?  could it be being obscured by another UIView that is opaque?

Comment: I've tried `messageBodyTxt.text`, which produces the same problem. I moved it to the top of the view hierarchy, still nothing, and also put a red background color to the TextView, which does show up, still no grey text as it should be.

Comment: Does it work with the default text color, or some other text?

Comment: If I take off the `setTextColor` and `setBackgroundColor`, then I just get a white box outlining the dimensions set by the `CGReckMake`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. The frame of the parent view was too small, and not being clipped, so I could see all of my other elements in the view showing up, but they were not clickable (eg. buttons and such)

As soon as I fixed the parent view frame to be the correct size, the `UITextView text magically showed up.

Thanks everyone you'd done great!

Comment: You can use IB for simple things like this. It's very easy and prevent some troubles.

Answer (score 2):

It's really strange. I create "1 view" project.
Then:
ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController: UIViewController {
    UITextView *exampleTxt;
}

@end
```

Go to ViewController.m (viewDidLoad):

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    exampleTxt = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)];
    [exampleTxt setText:@"Everything Ok"];
    [exampleTxt setColor:[UIColor redColor]]; //yes, it's deprecated, but works
    [self.view addSubview: exampleTxt]; //because its ViewController
}
```

And everything ok.
Looks like troubles in link your viewController with your MessageView. Try to use Interface Builder.
Or show more code.